# I'm getting an error when installing Ruby and RVM on the terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, gemfile

How do I uninstall the old ruby versions and how do can I update to GemFile to 2.4.2?

Sandys-MacBook-Pro:roughhouse-web sandychow$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.4.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.5
Sandys-MacBook-Pro:roughhouse-web sandychow$ rvm list

rvm rubies

ruby-2.1.5 [ missing bin/ruby ]
   ruby-2.2.5 [ missing bin/ruby ]
 * ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]

Answer (score 0):

To specify a Ruby version in your Gemfile, simply include the version towards the top:

For Ruby 2.4.2, you can do this:

```
# Gemfile

source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.4.2"

# ... your gems on the following lines ...
```

If you want to uninstall a Ruby version, execute:

```
$ rvm uninstall <version_number>
```

So to uninstall version 2.2.5, execute:

```
$ rvm uninstall 2.2.5
```

Note: don't include the `$` sign. That's just there to represent your terminal window.

More information on specifying Ruby versions in your Gemfile can be found at these links:

- [Heroku - Ruby versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions)
- [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/mrgqiw/specify-ruby-version-in-gemfile)

---

If you still experience issues, you may need to install or update `bundler`:

```
$ gem install bundler
```

or

```
$ gem update bundler
```

Comment: I tried that, it keeps giving me an error.

Sandys-MacBook-Pro:roughhouse-web sandychow$ rvm uninstall 2.2.5
ruby-2.2.5 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.2.5............................................................-
Error running '__rvm_rm_rf /Users/sandychow/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5',
please read /Users/sandychow/.rvm/log/1507761866_ruby-2.2.5/remove.rubies.log

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2959) may be helpful. It looks like you might be able to fix that by running: `rvm fix-permissions`

Comment: It works now. I don't know what happened to it and I was getting a lot of errors from the 2.2.5 version. But some guy helped me at work and typed rvm remove 2.2.5 and then reinstalled it and nwo it works.

Comment: yup! Thanks for helping too! I ran into the same issue again when I try to type "bundle update" and could not remove it.

 For anyone who needs help cleaning up all RVM traces go to https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting and scroll down to

"How do I completely clean out all traces of RVM from my system, including for system wide installs?"

Answer (score 0):

As your Gemfile specified ruby 2.2.5 and your rvm ruby version is 2.4.2, you can simply update the project gems bundle to fix the issue by doing

```
   bundle update
```

This will update all the gems in your Gemfile file to get compatible with your current ruby version.